# How do I resolve a Target Framework Error for Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I get the following error when I try to build my project

```
The $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for MyApp.Android (v9.0) is less than the minimum required $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for Xamarin.Forms (10.0). 
You need to increase the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for MyApp.Android.
```

My current project property settings are:
[image]

[image]

I really do not understand why I am still getting this error with these settings, this is a dire situation for me at the moment. Any help is much appreciated. I am using Xamarin Forms 5.0.

Comment: Did you try to delete the bin and obj files,and rebuild the project,if it still throw this exception,you could try to create a new project with the above settings.

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT I tried all those things unfortunately it did not work. The new project would definitely work so thanks for posting that. I found out that in the .csproj file the framework version was not changing automatically after setting it in properties. Had to manually change from V9.0 to V10.0

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that even after changing the target framework in the properties of my Android project it was not reflecting in the .csproj file. As a result, I simply unloaded the Android project and changed the following line from:

`<TargetFrameworkVersion>v9.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>`
to
`<TargetFrameworkVersion>v10.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>`

Simples